# How are anonymous classes compiled in Java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac, anonymous-class

I've heard that Java bytecode actually doesn't support any kind of unnamed classes. How does javac translate unnamned classes to named ones?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It synthesizes a name of the form `EnclosingClass$n`, where "n" is a counter for anonymous classes in `EnclosingClass`. Because using `$` in identifiers is discouraged, these names should not collide with any user-specified names.

Comment: `$` is a valid character, but it's not recommended to use it in user-defined names.

Comment: You can easily see this when you compile a class with anonymous inner classes, because you get multiple `*.class` files, with names like `EnclosingClass$n.class`.

Comment: Does the counter start from 0 or from 1.  And is it continuously numbered from top to bottom of a source file?